# Updating my Windows store app to Windows10

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store

I have an app in the Windows Store 8 released in good old 2010.
I'm planning to release an update for Windows 10, but i want to save my user base. 
Would adding a new version to the Store update my existing app (like in App Store or GooglePlay) or it would create a new instance ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You upload different app packages for different platforms (wp/win8/uwp) which are all associated with your single app. The user will automatically download the version appropriate for their device. If a win8 user upgrades to win10, and you have a win10 package for your app, then the app will be upgraded on the user's device.